# Custom button component event issue on disabled

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

Im having an issue with disabling a button in a shared component. This is the setup here

Shared custom button component

```
<button [disabled]="disabled">
    <span>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </span>
</button>
```

Usage

```
<shared-button-component [disabled]="true" (click)="doAction()">Test</shared-button-component>
```

Now thing is, when disabled is set to true, obviously because the button itself is disabled, its supposed to not actually allow a click event, but when I have this setup, it still causes doAction() to do it's actions, rather than stopping it. Is there something I am doing wrong or missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `(click)` event binding on the component itself, not on the button. So you click action is emitted by a click on the `<shared-button-component>` instead of the actual button.

Use a `@Output` to pass the click event up to that parent component. See: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#output

Comment: I feel that could work, and that would if I wanted a custom output for sure. Is there a way to override the (click) event of a parent container, and take the click event of its child elements instead?

Comment: I suppose if there isn't a way to do that though, is there a way to have a conditional styling for :host ?
I could achieve what I'd like just as easily if there were a conditional way to set :host{} as a css styling rule, though I cant seem to find something like that either.